# Correct way of setting hidden value fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, hidden-field

in javascript i am using this code to set the value of some hidden fields on a page that is not mine

```
let hiddenField = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"].class1');
for (k = 0; k < hiddenField.length; k++) {
        console.log("previous value: " + hiddenField[k].value);
        hiddenField[k].value = hiddenValue;
        console.log("new value: " + hiddenField[k].value);
        console.log(hiddenField[k]);
}
```

The problem is that only one of the two hidden values is being correctly setted, in fact the output I obtain on the console is

```
previous value: 0
new value: 4.5
<input type=​"hidden" name=​"left.result.0.stars" class=​"class1" value=​"4.5">​
previous value: 0
new value: 4.5
 <input type=​"hidden" name=​"right.result.0.stars" class=​"class1" value=​"0">​
```

as you can see when I print hiddenField[k].value the value is correctly setted but when I print the element on the console  the value has been not setted, what can be the problem?

Comment: What do you see (after that code runs) when you use the DOM inspector to look at the element?

Comment: Your code is working fine, as you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/qtj36uef/. Note that I changed the hidden inputs to text to make the demo clearer. You're seeing the original value in the console when you log the element as that is what was stored in the DOM. The `value` ***property*** of the Element object is what gets updated.

Comment: Assigning the value of an input doesn't change its HTML representation, so logging it won't show the update. You need to do `.setAttribute('value', hiddeValue)` for that.

Comment: But it's not really necessary. Assigning the value property will surely update what gets sent when the form is submitted.

Comment: If you want visual confirmation, just add **hiddenField[k].type = "text"** and it will convert the hidden field to a text field and you can see it on the page

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you for your clarifications, so why does the first hidden field element update its value correctly while the second one remains 0?

Comment: @Barmar even if I use setAttribute the value of the second hidden field still remains 0 when I print the element. For me it is necessary to update correctly the element since when I submit the form I get an error of the type "second hidden field has not been setted"

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5ecfk6r1/3/

Answer (score -1):

You can set value of hidden input like this:

```
<body>
  <input type="hidden" name="left.result.0.stars" class="class1" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="right.result.0.stars" class="class1" value="0" />
  <script>
    let hiddenField = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"].class1');
    let hiddenValue = 4.5;
    for (k = 0; k < hiddenField.length; k++) {
      console.log("previous value: " + hiddenField[k].value);
      hiddenField[k].value = hiddenValue;
      console.log("new value: " + hiddenField[k].value);
      console.log(hiddenField[k]);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

[This code works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFEQf.png)

Comment: this does not work, even if I use setAttribute the value of the second hidden field still remains 0 when I print the element

Comment: your code is working fine. What is your goal?

Comment: I still don't understand why the first hidden field value was set correctly while the second didn't. In fact when I print the element after I setted the value for the first hidden field I get
<input type=​"hidden" name=​"left.result.0.stars" class=​"class1" value=​"4.5"> which is correct while for the second I get​
 <input type=​"hidden" name=​"right.result.0.stars" class=​"class1" value=​"0">​  which is not correct since the value is 0 and not 4.5. this cause me problems when I send the form since I get error like "second hidden field has not been set"

Comment: Umm, where is your script on your HTML page? Can I see your whole code?

Comment: I share my whole code. But my code works fine using your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).